# Changing the Header and Footer in ClassicThesis package

Tags: header-footer, classicthesis

I have written a document in A4 setting and now I am trying to convert it into 6x9 inches. I have gone through `classicthesis-config.tex` and `classicthesis.sty`

```
% A5
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{@minionpro}}%
        {% Minion gets some extra sizes     
            \PackageInfo{classicthesis}{A5 paper, MinionPro}%
            \areaset[current]{310pt}{600pt}%
            \setlength{\marginparwidth}{3em}%
            \setlength{\marginparsep}{1.25em}%
        }{% Palatino or other
            \PackageInfo{classicthesis}{A5 paper, Palatino or other}%
            \areaset[current]{310pt}{600pt}%
            \setlength{\marginparwidth}{3em}%
            \setlength{\marginparsep}{1.25em}%
        }%
```

But this is not reducing the area between footer page numbers and text.

[image]

How can I adjust this space between to save area.

Comment: 1) you're using an old version of classicthesis 2) see all those ifthenelse? they only work if you're using a few standard paper sizes 3) you could simply use the three areaset and setlength commands just after you load classicthesis.sty with whichever numbers you need

Comment: 1. I got my version from [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-typographic-thesis). Please suggest the new version. 2. Yes I am aware of that, that's why I had to manually configure the `classicthesis-config.tex` file. 3. I did used the areaset, as mentioned above, but I am not able to decrease the gap between page number and text block.

Comment: 1) newest version here https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/ 2) 3) how is your paper size set in `documentclass`? I don't know how to reproduce what you're doing.

Comment: I think this is what you need `\setlength{\footskip}{10pt}`. And to learn more about how the page is constructed, refer to koma-script documentation here ctan.org/pkg/koma-script

Comment: Thank you very much, setting that worked. Can you please write that in the answer so I can mark it solved? And I used geometry on `a5paper`. Also I updated to v4.6 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance between text area and the page footer can be controlled by `\footskip`, as in `\setlength{\footskip}{10pt}`. Classicthesis uses koma-script package areaset with options `headinclude, footinclude` to set the text area size, so [koma-script documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) is the place to go for more details.